WIFI works, but wired connection does not on Linux
I have a simple network consisting of a internet modem/router supplied by my internet provider (Ziggo). This gives me WIFI and wired connections.
I also have a website (hosted somewhere else) that's not doing anything now, and I purchased DNS redirection so that the DNS name of my website points to the ip address of my connection to my provider.
If you like, you can try : www.hanslammerts.nl.
Here's the strange thing:
I can go to the website using my laptop and phone.
I cannot go to the website from a freshly installed PC (running Debian 12) or another PC (running W10).
I see a SYN-SENT and eventually the connection times out.
The only difference is that the last two machines have a wired connection, my laptop and my phone obviously do not.
When I disable the wired connection on my Debian PC, and enable the WIFI, I can reach my website.
I do not understand why I can't go to my website from these two PCs using a wired connection, but through WIFI there's no problem.
Other websites, however, work perfectly from those PCs, also with the wired connection, so I'm guessing there's nothing wrong with my router/cables.
Tried many things, but even a freshly installed PC (wired) refuses to connect.
I'm really at a loss here. Any suggestions, please ?

The problem described in the question doesn't match the title.

Is it the same router you are talking about for the two types of connection? Does it make a difference if you access with the IP instead of the domain name? (Is it the only site that is problematic? No problem with Google or StackExchange?)

As @TomYan suggesta, try changing DNS resolution, e.g., Google or Cloudflare.

Yes, the router is the same for both wired and wifi connections.
And yes, it is only that site that is problematic. No problems with other sites.
Trying to reach the site with DNS name or ip address makes no difference. Still SYN-SENT.
Also tried several DNS servers, makes no difference.
